# SQLAlchemy ORM complex filters

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm

I wrote an API that was directly using psycopg2 to interface with a PostgreSQL database but decided to re-write to use SQLAlchemy ORM. For the most part I'm very happy with the transition, but there are a few of trickier things I did that have been tough to translate. I was able to build a query to do what I wanted, but I'd much rather handle it with a HybridProperty/HybridMethod or perhaps a Custom Comparator (tried both but couldn't get them to work). I'm fairly new to SQLAlchemy ORM so I'd be happy to explore all options but I'd prefer something in the database model rather than the API code.

For background, there are several loosely coupled API consumers that have a few mandatory identifying columns that belong to the API and then a LargeBinary column that they can basically do whatever they want with. In the code below, the API consumers need to be able to select messages based on their own identifiers that are not parsed by the API (since each consumer is likely different).

Old code:

```
select_sql = sql.SQL("""SELECT {field1}
                    FROM {table}
                    WHERE {field2}={f2}
                    AND {field3}={f3}
                    AND {field4}={f4}
                    AND left(encode({f5}, 'hex'), {numChar})={selectBytes} # Relevant clause
                    AND {f6}=false;
                 """
                 ).format(field1=sql.Identifier("key"),
                          field2=sql.Identifier("f2"),
                          field3=sql.Identifier("f3"),
                          field4=sql.Identifier("f4"),
                          field5=sql.Identifier("f5"),
                          field6=sql.Identifier("f6"),
                          numChar=sql.Literal(len(data['bytes'])),
                          table=sql.Identifier("incoming"),
                          f2=sql.Literal(data['2']),
                          selectBytes=sql.Literal(data['bytes']),
                          f3=sql.Literal(data['3']),
                          f1=sql.Literal(data['1']))

try:
    cur = incoming_conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(select_sql)
    keys = [x[0] for x in cur.fetchall()]
    cur.close()
    return keys, 200
except psycopg2.DatabaseError as error:
    logging.error(error)
    incoming_conn.reset()
    return "Error reading from DB", 500
```

New code:

```
try:
    session = Session()
    messages = (
                session.query(IncomingMessage)
                .filter_by(deleted=False)
                .filter_by(f2=data['2'])
                .filter_by(f3=data['3'])
                .filter_by(f4=data['4'])
                .filter(func.left(func.encode(IncomingMessage.payload, # Relevant clause
                                              'hex'),
                                  len(data['bytes'])) == data['bytes'])
                )
    keys = [x.key for x in messages]
    session.close()
    return keys, 200
except exc.OperationalError as error:
    logging.error(error)
    session.close()
    return "Database failure", 500
```

The problem that I kept running into was how to limit the number of stored bytes that were being compared. I don't think it's really a problem in the Comparator, but I feel like there would be a performance cost if I were loading several megabytes just to compare the first eight or so bytes.

Comment: Did you end up finding a solid solution for this? I am trying to do something similar (translating a bunch of code that interfaces directly with a PostgreSQL database into the SQLAlchemy ORM).

Comment: Nope. I pretty much just made peace with it for now. Once I finish I'll look for any major performance problems, but for the time being I'm just moving on.